# Fastest Haskell library sort implementation

Tags: haskell, sorting

I am implementing an application in Haskell and, for sorting, I use the library function `Data.List.sort`. However, I was wondering whether this is the fastest sort implementation in the Haskell standard library (perhaps lists are not the best choice for efficient sorting).

I have found different alternatives, e.g. [heap sort on arrays](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/heapsort/0.1.0/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray-Heapsort.html), [sort on sequences](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html#g:10) (but the documentation does not say what kind of algorithm is used).

My question is: what is the fastest sorting implementation (container type + sort function) provided by the Haskell standard library? Is there some documentation page listing all library sort functions and comparing them wrt performance?

**EDIT**

To provide some more context, I am running a benchmark. I have written a simple program in C, Java, Python and Haskell that

1. Reads 1000000 strings (lines) from a text file.
2. Sorts the strings using a built-in (library) sorting algorithm.
3. Writes the sorted list of strings to a file.

For each implementation, I only measure the sorting time (leaving out the time needed for disk IO).
Running the benchmark on Ubuntu 12.04, I get

- C (gcc 4.6.3, `qsort` on `char **`): 0.890 s
- Java (OpenJDK 64-Bit 1.7.0_09, `Collections.sort()` on `java.util.LinkedList<String>`): 1.307 s
- Python (Python 2.7.3, `list.sort()`): 1.072 s
- Haskell (GHC 7.4.1, `Data.List.sort` on `[Data.ByteString.UTF8.ByteString]`): 11.864 s

So I wonder if there is another data type / library function in Haskell that can give better performance.

Comment: You might avoid some overhead if you use unboxed arrays, they tend to be nice and quick

Comment: Could you post here (or to some pastebin) your testing programs, so that we can work with them?

Comment: @Petr Pudlák: All of them? Or would the Haskell version be sufficient? It is a project I am working on and I would prefer to post only the parts relevant to sorting in Haskell.

Comment: Sure, Haskell will be enough.

Comment: @Petr Pudlák: Here it is http://pastebin.com/EjttY212

Comment: @Petr Pudlák : Here is my test data: http://depositfiles.com/files/9ou6kjaya

Comment: Thanks. Just a note, you should `deepseq` the input list as well, otherwise add a small overhead to the timed code (try replacing `sort` with `id`).

Comment: Thanks to you for taking a look at the code. Indeed, there was some overhead due to the input list not being completely reduced.

Comment: There is no one sort to rule them all. Different sorts will be best for different kinds of data.

Comment: @whatsisname: And what would you use for sorting strings? I do not need to rule them all, just to sort strings as fast as possible.

Comment: @Giorgio Sort them by parts. Namely, sort by the first character, then by the second, then by the third, and so on. Basically, use Bucket Sort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with `Data.List.sort` is that it uses merge sort, which creates new lists during each pass. So a lot of time is spent on allocating and freeing memory.

Surprisingly, AFAIK there isn't a sorting library for [mutable arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_IO_arrays_.28module_Data.Array.IO.29), which are likely to be faster. So I tried to make one and put it on github: [**marray-sort**](https://github.com/ppetr/marray-sort). It needs rigorous testing, polishing and optimizing too, but so far it already seems to be significantly faster than `Data.List.sort`.

If you make any experiments with it, I'd be happy to see the results. I put your (slightly modified) benchmark to [src-test/Test.hs](https://github.com/ppetr/marray-quicksort/blob/master/src-test/Test.hs) for convenience. Don't forget to compile everything with [`-O2`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/options-optimise.html) to trigger the necessary compiler optimizations.

**Edit:** I found out now that there is an implementation if introsort for mutable vectors in [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-algorithms/0.3.2/doc/html/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Intro.html). According to my measurements, it is slightly faster (5-10%) than my attempt above for `MArray`s
See also: [How does one sort with Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3655329/1333025).

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1). I have also written a quick sort (and merge sort) for mutable arrays. I am eager to look at your solution (even though it will have to wait until the coming week end).

Comment: Sorry that it took me so long to answer. I am working on this project in my free time and I kept postponing it. I have now tried out your implementation and it is definitely faster than the `Data.List.Sort`. I also have implemented my own merge sort on mutable arrays and it runs a bit faster than introsort, at least on my examples. I haven't tried `Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro.sort` yet.